# How to add a do_action on refreshing of WP customizer?

Tags: php, customization, jquery, ajax, javascript

I want to clear the cache of a plugin on refreshing the preview of the WordPress customizer because I can only see the changes I make if the cache of that plugin is refreshed.

This because the theme mod values are stored in css files that need to have a refresh of the cache before you can see the changes. Since these css files are connected to theme mod values, I need to refresh the cache of the plugin on refreshing the customizer preview.

I have come this far with PHP:

```
function px_clear_bb_cache() {
FLBuilderModel::delete_asset_cache_for_all_posts();
}
do_action( 'customize_save', 'px_clear_bb_cache' );
```

The cache is now refreshed after saving **and closing** :( the customizer.

I think I need to hook into the customizer with JS + Ajax but can't figure out how to do this.

Would be great if someone could help me out here.

Basically the PHP command "FLBuilderModel::delete_asset_cache_for_all_posts();" needs to fire every time when refreshing the preview of the customizer.

Comment: Do you want to clear the plugin cache for all changes, even ones that aren't saved?

Comment: Yes for all changes, even unsaved ones.

Comment: Why are you using `do_action` ? Shouldn't it be `add_action( 'customize_save', 'px_clear_bb_cache' );` ? @Bob

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:

1. Create a PHP file "purge-bb-cache.php"
2. Create a JS script like below in functions.php

purge-bb-cache.php

```
<?php 
  FLBuilderModel::delete_asset_cache_for_all_posts();
 ?>
```

JS script:

```
// Add JS to customizer
function print_customizer_js() {     
?>
<script>

// Purge BB Cache On Save Customizer
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("input#save").click(function(){
//var ajaxurl = "<?php echo ( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/script.php' ); ?>";

jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/assets/purge-bb-cache.php',
success: function(data) {
console.log("Purged BB Cache");
}
});
});
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('customize_controls_print_scripts', 'print_customizer_js');
```